# Javascript to convert degrees, to decimal, and UTM

Tags: javascript, maps, utm

I´m trying to convert Degrees, Minutes and Seconds, to decimal degrees, and finally to UTM. Is there any example or library available for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful libraries for doing this kind of thing, in particular [geolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) and [utm-latlng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utm-latlng).

Once we import these we can convert from Degrees, Minutes, Seconds with geolib and then to UTM with utm-latlng:

```
const geolib = require("geolib");
const UTM = require("utm-latlng");
const utm = new UTM();

const input = { lat: "34° 3′ 12.96″ N", lon: "118° 14′ 34.8″ W" };
const decimalCoords = geolib.toDecimal(input);

console.log("Input:", input);
console.log("Degrees/Minutes/Seconds To Decimal:", decimalCoords);
console.log("UTM:", utm.convertLatLngToUtm(decimalCoords.lat, decimalCoords.lon, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a solution without npm?, classic javascript? Only is possible. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an example of source code written in vanilla.js for this, however the source code for the DMS conversion in geolib is freely viewable: https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib/blob/master/src/sexagesimalToDecimal.ts. And also the code for the UTM conversion: https://github.com/shahid28/utm-latlng/blob/master/UTMLatLng.js. You may be able to adapt this for your own needs!

Comment: The links you provided was very useful to me. I finally used these ones.

Comment: Great, I'm glad they were of help to you!